# Url rewriting in php from htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have written this code in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^signin signin.php
```

But when I am trying to make link like `<a href="signin">Xyz </a>`

It showing me this error:

> Not Found
>   The requested URL /abctra/signin was not found on this server.
>   Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

What could be the problem is it a problem of hosting I am using Godaddy Linux hosting. If any changes needed to be done on the server do tell me.

The code is running on the localhost nicely. Just not running on the hosting account.

Comment: Are you sure there is a `signin.php` file in that folder?

Comment: can you show your .htaccess code?

Comment: and what url you are getting after writing this in .htaccess?

Comment: Where do you have the .htaccess file? On the folder /abctra ?

Comment: abctra.com is the link you can check it i have just uploaded a demo on it. Either click on Signin or on Register its giving same problem.

Comment: Ricoxor just using simple PHP

Comment: Lepanto -> abctra is my hosting folder i have just placed the .htaccess in the folder

Comment: There is no issue with what you have in .htaccess, Rishap, I think signin.php has some issue. I think you have used an wrong path. Check the code.

Comment: Lepanto this code is correct the same code is running one my other hosting account of big rock linux server. Its not working on Godaddy. Thats why i have mentioned my hosting server name. may be any changes needed to be made in the settings of Godaddy

Comment: abctra.com/signin.php is showing an error, did you check that? It is this error explained on a different manner when you try abctra.com/signin

Comment: Check In the Apache ERROR LOGS

Comment: Lepanto i am rewriting the url from abctra.com/signin.php to abctra.com/signin so if u will try to open abctra.com/signin.php it will give error.

Comment: I know that you are trying to use abctra.com/signin which will run the code that is in abctra.com/signin.php. But I'm sure there is issue with signin.php and not in htaccess. I hope you have PHP header redirection in signin.php which is pointing to an incorrect path.

Comment: No its is opening the abctra.com/signin.php

Comment: Can you create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then open `http://abctra.com/info.php` to check what is its `DOCUMENT_ROOT` value.

Comment: Anubhava -> its showing two path one for the main domain and other for subdomain. and abctra path is showing in the subdomain /var/chroot/home/content/73/7312973/html/abctra.
You and also check the link [link]http://abctra.com/info.php

Comment: What to do with DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: I am not getting the solution guys its really very urgent for me... Have to upload the website by tomorrow.. the code is running on the localhost nicely. Just not running on the hosting account.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code looks fine try to check if mod_rewrite Apache module is enabled, with shared hosting you might not have SSH access but you can check it via php using the below code

```
in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules());
```

Comment: Opensource -> what it will return in array ... Boolean or value

Comment: It would return an array of all modules enabled

Comment: Opensouce its giving error "Call to undefined function apache_get_modules()"

Comment: You can try checking this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178173/alternatives-to-apache-get-modules-to-get-list-of-loaded-apache-modules

Comment: You could check what option your PHP is compiled with as mentioned in the above link

Comment: Also You could try adding Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews as the first line in your htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

You almost had, the following should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^signin$ /signin.php
```